# How do i find area under the graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm currently working on graph plotting website for my homework.
I have finished drawing graph using graph.js and i wonder how can i calculate the value of area under the graph

This is screenshot of my graph
[image]

I want to find all the grey area under the graph.

Here is the code to create graph with graph.js:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
            data : graphValue,
            borderwidth : 1,
            label : lineLabel,
            fill : true,
            lineTension : 0,
            pointBackgroundColor : 'rgba (83,81,84,1)',
            borderColor : 'rgba(83,81,84,1)'
    }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: graphName
      },
        scales : {
            yAxes : [{
                ticks : {
                    beginAtZero : true,
                    min :0,
                    max :200
                }
            }]
        }
    }
    });
```

and my value is just array of number that i pass from html page :

```
var graphValue = [98,12,19,64,85,91,56,181,171,90];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your graph, each part is a **trapezium** with height = 1.
You just need to loop through the `graphValue` array and calculate the area of each trapezium and add it to the total area under curve.

Formula for area of trapezium is:

> Area = `0.5 * (a + b) * h`
>   where `a` & `b` are two parallel sides of the trapezium and `h` is the distance between them.

The code below can solve your problem.

```
var graphValue = [98,12,19,64,85,91,56,181,171,90];
var area = 0; // Initially set area to zero
var height = 1; // distance between parallel sides of the trapezium
for(var i=1; i<graphValue.length; i++) {
    area += 0.5 * (graphValue[i] + graphValue[i-1]) * height;
    // here a = graphValue[i] 
    // b = graphValue[i-1]
}

console.log(area); // 773 in this example
```